# How to search by API OpenWeatherApi city?

Tags: swift, api, search, openweathermap

I created these requests, I don’t know if I asked them correctly. If someone can tell, they will be grateful. Here is my code. I need to search for a city in the search and so that the weather is displayed in the table. Please help and tell me how to set and where to fix it. Or did I set the functions and methods incorrectly?  error

> "The data couldn’t be read because it is missing."

```
import UIKit

class SearchViewController: UIViewController,UISearchResultsUpdating, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var filteredCity: [OpenWeather] = []
    
   // var searchCity: [OpenWeather]=[]
    let wetherApi = WeatherManager()
    var cityWeather = [OpenWeather]()
    let netSer = NetworkService()
    let searchController = UISearchController()
    
    var isSearchBarEmpty: Bool {
      return searchController.searchBar.text?.isEmpty ?? true
    }

    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        wetherApi.fetchCurrentWeather(city: "London")
  
      
    }
    
      
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        self.filteredCity = self.cityWeather.filter { (city:OpenWeather) -> Bool in
            if city.city.lowercased().contains(self.searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased()){
                return true
            }else {
                return false
            }
        }
        //Update the results TableView
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
   
    
    @objc func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cityWeather.count

      }
    
    
    @objc(tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:) internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CityTableViewCell
        
        cell.cityTemp.text = cityWeather[indexPath.row].city
        cell.cityTemp.text = "\(cityWeather[indexPath.row].main.tempCelsius)"
        
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

My structure weather:

```
  import Foundation
import UIKit

struct OpenWeather: Codable  {
    let coord:Coordinate
    let city:String
    let weathertwo:[WeatherTwo]
    let main: Main
    
   
}

struct Coordinate: Codable {
    let lan:Float
    let lot:Float
     enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey  {
    case lan = "lat"
    case lot = "lon"
    }
}

struct WeatherTwo: Codable {
    let main: String
    let description: String 
}

struct Main: Codable {
    private let temp: Double
     var tempCelsius: Double {
       get {
           return (temp - 32) / 1.8
       }
     }
    private let temp_min: Double
     var tempCelsiusmin: Double {
       get {
           return (temp - 32) / 1.8
       }
     }
    private let temp_max: Double
     var tempCelsiusmax: Double {
       get {
           return (temp - 32) / 1.8
       }
     }
    let pressure: Int
    let humidity: Int
    
}
```

My code Api codable download:

```
struct WeatherManager {
        //Deliberately deleted "q=London" within the url, because it needs to be customizable with a different city
        
        
    func fetchCurrentWeather(city: String){
         let URL_API = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="
        let CITY_ID = city
        //let URL_API_KEY = "<api_key>"
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
       
        
        let urlString = URL_API + CITY_ID + "&appid=cfe547d810fc4ad95e8f24187c6b08da"
            
            guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
                print("Error building URL")
                return
            }
            
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if let error = error {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                        return
                    }
                    
                    guard let data = data, let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                        print("Invalid data or response")
                        return
                    }
                    
                    do {
                        if response.statusCode == 200 {
                            let items = try JSONDecoder().decode(OpenWeather.self, from: data)
                            print(items)
                        } else {
                            print("Response wasn't 200. It was: " + "\n\(response.statusCode)")
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
                
            }
            task.resume()
        
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You most often get a more detailed error message if you do `print(error)` in your catch clauses instead of `print(error.localizedDescription)`.

Comment: The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.

Comment: gives me such an error. It seems to me that I wrote it wrong func UpdateSearch ?

Comment: Unrelated but you can get all temperatures in Celsius by appending `&units=metric` to the URL string

Comment: Yes, how to do it? Set the city and add to the table

Comment: `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?units=metric&q=`

Comment: Already added  can you please city SearchBar func

Comment: You have to download the city list mentioned in the answer. Then create a `City` model and decode the JSON. Display the filtered cities according to the search query. If you want to show the temperatures you have to perform one `openweathermap` request per displayed city.

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: Note FYI, at: "https://openweathermap.org/current#bulk", mentions 
`..Please note that buit-in API requests by city name, zip-codes and city id will be deprecated soon.`, they recommend using the `geocoding api`.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few reasons this happens.

If you look at the response the [API gives you](https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=london&appid=cfe547d810fc4ad95e8f24187c6b08da), you will find that:

1. The keys `weathertwo` and `city` do not exist in the response, yet they are present in your `OpenWeather` struct. You need to make them optional or provide your default values by overriding the init if you don't always expect this data to be present
2. Have a look at the `coord` object in the response

```
"coord": {
"lon": -0.1257,
"lat": 51.5085
}
```

Compare the spelling of keys with your coord struct:

```
struct Coordinate: Codable {
    let lan:Float
    let long:Float
}
```

If you want to use different variable names, you need to look at using `CodingKeys`

However, the simplest fix I believe is changing your `OpenWeather` struct to this:

```
struct OpenWeather: Codable {
    let coord: Coordinate
    let city: String?
    let weathertwo: [WeatherTwo]?
    let main: Main
}
```

and fixing coords to this:

```
struct Coordinate: Codable {
    let lat: Float
    let lon: Float
}
```

should get rid of the error and give you the data you need as I can see data from the Open Weather API printed on the console:

```
OpenWeather(coord: TestApp.Coordinate(lat: 25.2582, lon: 55.3047), city: nil, weathertwo: nil, main: TestApp.Main(temp: 300.38, temp_min: 299.31, temp_max: 301.29, pressure: 1008, humidity: 54))
```

There are other improvements that could be made such as using camel case for the variables with CodingKeys but that is something you can decide later.

Give this a go and see if it resolves your issue.

**Update**

As you rightly pointed out, you asked how to get the list of cities supported by Open Weather.

I had a quick look, it does not look like they have an API to get a list of all the cities. Their API seems to support you sending a city name and it will send back to you the weather data for that city.

However, they provide their [list of cities here](http://bulk.openweathermap.org/sample/)

I think the file `history.city.list.json.gz` has all the city data which might need to be included in your app or somewhere online if you wish.

Have a look.

Comment: There are other suggestions. The option is not correct, I changed it did not Work  Float -> Double .

Comment: I didn't say change Float to Double. I said, just fix the spelling of the keys and manage optionals. Once I fixed that, the data from the API get's printed on the console as expected. I edited my answer to show you the correct data from the API is printed to the console.

Comment: Yes, I changed the error disappeared, but how can I write the code and make the search by city work and give out a table with the temperature? Please

Comment: @Aleksandr0009 You want to search for city and show temperature in table view .. why do you use table view for this as you will only show data for one city at a time ? I need to understand more about the user flow, they search for one city, then what should happen in the UI, they search for second city, then what should happen in the UI ? Also not clear, what is the purpose of filter in your question. I want to help you but I need you to clarify more the flow and the end goal you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I need auto-complete during the search and give out city options and when you click on the city it shows the temperature in the cells. For example, "P" Praga, Paris,Porto .....

Comment: @Aleksandr0009 - but where is database / array of cities ? Do you have this in your app ? Also, I think you should put this in a separate question because there are many parts to give you one answer. Here we solve the JSON issue you had, but you want way for autocomplete suggestions, making call to api for each different city etc so I think this should be a separate question as there are many things.

Comment: In general, I asked the question of the cities API search. Read the title

Comment: @Aleksandr0009 - you are right. It seems like they don't have an API for cities that I could find but I could find the source of the cities. See some updates I have added to the answer.